# Silverlight - Highlight List<> of words/prhases within TextBox

Tags: silverlight, text, textbox, highlight

I am new to Silverlight and have a requirement to highlight (or change font color) all words and phrases wtihin a TextBox that match a list of words/phrases.  At first I though this would be easy, but the more I look into it, the more confused I get.

My goal is to write something reusable so I can also apply the logic to a RadGridView later.  I've seen a few examples of stuff close to what I need, but it's beyond my Silverlight level at this point.

I want to write this myself to get a better understanding of how some of the Silverlight internals work.  Can someone point me in the right direction of where to start on something like this?  Should this be implemented in a control?  Should I use a behavior?  I'm using Silverlight 4.

Once I know where to start, I am sure I can get this done - with some help from you guys of course ;-)

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 1):

How about using the RadRichTextBox (I assume you have a licence for it as you mentionned the RadGridView)?

There's also a good sample project on [Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/richtextbox/programatically-highlight-text.aspx) that is doing exactly what you want to do.